# Decoding HID descritor to match RAW HID Data

Tags: usb, hid, descriptor

i'm trying to decode a HID RAW data stream of a multitouch screen that i'm reading from /dev/hidraw2 when connected to a linux computer.

i've already have a HID report descriptor of my multitouch screen and a 64byte stream coming from my screen.
[1 finger touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6gBU.png) 
so far i can understand that 02 - report id / 04 - 07 if pressed or not pressed / xx - i dont know // xx xx cordinates //yy yy cordinates. but it must be a way to read the hid descriptor and translate that for this data stream that i'm getting.

```
Usage Page (Digitizer),             ; Digitizer (0Dh)
Usage (Touchscreen),                ; Touch screen (04h, application collection)
Collection (Application),
    Report ID (2),
    Usage (Finger),                 ; Finger (22h, logical collection)
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage Page (Digitizer),     ; Digitizer (0Dh)
        Usage (Tip Switch),         ; Tip switch (42h, momentary control)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (1),
        Report Size (1),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (In Range),           ; In range (32h, momentary control)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (47h),
        Input (Variable),
        Report Count (5),
        Input (Constant, Variable),
        Report Size (8),
        Usage (51h),
        Report Count (1),
        Input (Variable),
        Usage Page (Desktop),       ; Generic desktop controls (01h)
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (32767),
        Report Size (16),
        Usage (X),                  ; X (30h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
        Usage (Y),                  ; Y (31h, dynamic value)
        Input (Variable),
    End Collection,
    Usage Page (Digitizer),         ; Digitizer (0Dh)
    Usage (54h),
    Report Count (1),
    Report Size (8),
    Input (Variable),
    Usage (55h),
    Logical Maximum (10),
    Feature (Variable),
End Collection,
Usage (0Eh),
Collection (Application),
    Report ID (4),
    Usage (23h),
    Collection (Logical),
        Usage (52h),
        Logical Minimum (0),
        Logical Maximum (10),
        Report Size (8),
        Report Count (1),
        Feature (Variable),
    End Collection,
End Collection,
Usage Page (FF00h),                 ; FF00h, vendor-defined
Usage (01h),
Collection (Application),
    Report ID (250),
    Usage (01h),
    Usage Minimum (01h),
    Usage Maximum (3Fh),
    Logical Minimum (0),
    Logical Maximum (-1),
    Report Size (8),
    Report Count (63),
    Input (Variable),
    Report ID (18),
    Usage (02h),
    Usage Minimum (01h),
    Usage Maximum (3Fh),
    Output (Variable),
    Report ID (16),
    Usage (03h),
    Usage Minimum (01h),
    Usage Maximum (3Fh),
    Logical Minimum (0),
    Logical Maximum (-1),
    Report Size (8),
    Report Count (7),
    Feature (Variable),
End Collection
```

Comment: Can you post a hex dump of the HID descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

The input report 02 decodes as the following C-language structure (see below). Basically it comprises a 1-byte report id, 10 lots of finger touch data (flags, contact id, x, y), and a 1-byte contact count (i.e. number of touches detected). The total input report length should be 1+10x(1+1+2+2)+1 = 62 bytes:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Digitizer Device Page inputReport 02 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
                                                     // Collection: CA:TouchScreen CL:Finger
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange : 1;         // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence : 1;      // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier;   // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX;                    // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY;                    // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_1 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_1 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_1 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_1; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_1;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_1;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_2 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_2 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_2 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_2; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_2;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_2;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_3 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_3 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_3 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_3; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_3;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_3;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_4 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_4 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_4 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_4; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_4;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_4;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_5 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_5 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_5 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_5; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_5;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_5;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_6 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_6 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_6 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_6; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_6;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_6;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_7 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_7 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_7 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_7; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_7;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_7;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_8 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_8 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_8 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_8; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_8;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_8;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_9 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_9 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_9 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_9; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_9;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_9;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
                                                     // Collection: CA:TouchScreen
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenContactCount;              // Usage 0x000D0054: Contact Count, Value = 0 to 10
} inputReport02_t;
```